# Not able to populate combo box label IN EXTJS

Tags: extjs4, extjs4.2

I am using Extjs 4.2 and I have a combo box field on my page. When I am updating this page, I need to show the selected value in the combo box. If I use static data it will work properly, but when I am loading data from the database then data is coming but it is displaying the value (not the label) for the selected combo box.

I have done the work around by using the `select` method of the combo box, but I need to iterate the store for getting the selected value. The store value does not start at 1 but starts at 100, and the `select` method of the combo box uses the index for the list.

Below is the code you can check, but this is not working for multiple combo boxes.

```
var specilizationComboBox = Ext.getCmp("doctorMasterVO.specilizationFkId");

var specilizationValue = 0;

specilizationStore.each(function (record) {
    if (record.get('value') != dataRead.dataVO.doctorMasterVO.specilizationFkId) {
        specilizationValue = specilizationValue + 1;
    }
    else {
        return false; 
    }
});

specilizationComboBox.select(specilizationComboBox.store.data.items[specilizationValue]);
```

Please tell me there is any other way to do this because iterating over the whole store is not a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out these methods:

[find](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-find)

[findBy](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-findBy)

[findRecord](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-findRecord)

[findExact](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-findExact)

Basicly what you want to do is something like this:

```
var myId = dataRead.dataVO.doctorMasterVO.specilizationFkId;
var record = store.findRecord("id", myId);
specilizationComboBox.select(record);
```

Where "id" is the name of the field you are trying to find a match for in your store.
Note that myRecord could be null if the record is not there or if the store is not properly **loaded**.

To make sure the store is loaded you could execute the code above in a load handler:

```
specilizationComboBox.getStore().load({
    scope: this,
    callback: function(records, operation, success) {
      //code goes here
    }
});
```

If you are not sure if the store has loaded you could check the [getCount](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-getCount) method.